# Getting InvalidParameterValue: Missing final '@domain' while sending email in aws ses nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am using lambda function to send email using aws ses. My account is in production and domain is also verified but still i am not able to send email using aws ses. I am getting this error

> 

```
2022-12-28T09:57:42.851Z    9334073b-987b-47aa-bb57-54a92ad7d09e    ERROR   InvalidParameterValue: Missing final '@domain'
    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'InvalidParameterValue',
  time: 2022-12-28T09:57:42.849Z,
  requestId: 'e5854086-b690-4faf-bb79-f6e54a655508',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 67.29353748593772
```

```js
  const params = {
    Destination: { 
      ToAddresses: ["alpha.prime0502@gmail.com"]
    },
    Message: { 
      Body: { 
        Html: {
         Charset: "UTF-8",
         Data: resetPasswordEmail(name,passcode)
        },
       },
       Subject: {
        Data: subject
       }
    },
    Source: "readwise.mksmohan.com", 
  };




  try { 
    const result = await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet where you're making the request to SES?

Comment: const params = {
    Destination: { 
      ToAddresses: ["email"]
    },
    Message: { 
      Body: { 
        Html: {
         Charset: "UTF-8",
         Data: resetPasswordEmail(name,passcode)
        },
       },
       Subject: {
        Data: subject
       }
    },
    Source: "readwise.mksmohan.com", 
  };

  


  try { 
    const result = await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

Comment: Resolved my issue, I included 'no-reply@domain-name' or 'admin@domain' instead of solely using the domain name.